# Google Translate Sandbox

Tags: rest, google-translate

I am attempting to use the Google translate API for a project, and I want to test it before I buy into it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to test their REST client to make sure that it meets my needs before I pay?

Answer (score 0):

Google says, "[No sandbox is available](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-translate-api/MkDZXUsYl28)," but you can [access Google Translate indirectly from within Google Apps](http://www.badrit.com/blog/2011/12/25/free-google-translate-api-v2#.VEbbaXW9_8s). It doesn't look very RESTful, though.